# Run a GUI app on remote computer from SSH through a third server in between

Tags: ssh, terminal, gui, x-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Basic ssh tunneling through generic linux ssh server/client](https://superuser.com/questions/190351/basic-ssh-tunneling-through-generic-linux-ssh-server-client)

Recalling this question: [Run a GUI app on remote computer from SSH](https://superuser.com/questions/230138/run-a-gui-app-on-remote-computer-from-ssh)
I add more complexity asking if: 
It is possible to Run a GUI app on remote computer from SSH passing by another computer, again through SSH ?

For instance, I want to replicate something like that: 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-mac-osx-x11-forwarding-over-ssh-howto.html
but the scenario is:

My Laptop -> ssh usrA@Server_A -> ssh usrB@Server B

I don't have yet the access in order to try this, but I've been asked to advise if I know a method of doing that

(maybe ssh -X Server_A and then ssh -X Server_B ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First run:

```
ssh -Y usrA@srvA
```

and then:

```
ssh -Y usrB@srvB
```

Your display will be forwarded correctly to your laptop.

Comment: thank you! I tested it with my laptop and 2 ubuntu virtual machines and it works smoothly!

Answer (score 0):

I would say YES.

TO do this you should create an ssh tunnel on the Server_A.

How to do this:

http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html

Comment: No, not this way.